# ServiceStack.OrmLite. CreateTable method lacks option to define COLLATION?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I found out that the tables created followed the `collation_database`/`collation_server` variables in MySql.

I was confused for a while why "Ö" and "O" was interpreted the same way, but when I realized the collation was the problem, I wanted OrmLite to create the tables with the correct collation. However, I didn't find any way to use the CreateTable method and define the collation.

Am I missing something, or do I have to manually, after the `CreateTable` call finished, run a custom SQL where I alter the table, like:

> alter table convert to character set latin1 collate latin1_swedish_ci;

Or is there a way to do this in OrmLite already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite doesn’t support creating tables with a custom collation itself but you could use the [Pre/Post Custom SQL Hooks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#pre--post-custom-sql-hooks-when-creating-and-dropping-tables) to execute Custom SQL before and after tables are created with the attributes below:

```
[PreCreateTable(runSqlBeforeTableCreated)]
[PostCreateTable(runSqlAfterTableCreated)]
[PreDropTable(runSqlBeforeTableDropped)]
[PostDropTable(runSqlAfterTableDropped)]
public class Table {}
```